# How to get svn update (e) to show merge conflicts in diff3 form?

Tags: svn, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

If I run svn update, and hit a merge conflict I get an (e) edit option.  However, that edit session appears to only provide 2-way diffs, not the diff3 format I would have expected.  Example:

```
<<<<<<< .mine
  LGSYSTEMLOGBLOCK     *pSLb;
//   DMLOGREC          *pDmLogrec;
=======
   LGSYSTEMLOGBLOCK    *pSLb       = NULL;
//   DMLOGREC          *pDmLogrec     = NULL;
>>>>>>> .r30337
```

Here I happen to know that my change relative to the original was just commenting out the line.  The commit that I have merged also did that, but also initialized it.  I'd like to see the following in the merge conflict edit session (as with git):

```
<<<<<<< .mine
  LGSYSTEMLOGBLOCK     *pSLb;
//   DMLOGREC          *pDmLogrec;
||||||| .orig
  LGSYSTEMLOGBLOCK     *pSLb;
   DMLOGREC          *pDmLogrec;
=======
   LGSYSTEMLOGBLOCK    *pSLb       = NULL;
//   DMLOGREC          *pDmLogrec     = NULL;
>>>>>>> .r30337
```

Answer (score 0):

In `[helpers]` section of SVN's config file define (one of, detect it by hand - can't recall on the fly) `diff-cmd`|`diff3-cmd`|`merge-tool-cmd`